# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error de php y mysqli?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario de login  pero a la hora de enviar los datos de los inputs me da el siguiente error:
Notice: Undefined index: usernames in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruba1\panel\load.php on line 36
He buscado por internet y he encontrado que es a causa de no asignarle valor name a los inputs, (cosa que yo ya he hecho y aún sigue pasando lo mismo). Me gustaría crear yo los usuarios en la base de datos, tipo el mítico username admin y eso. Como también soy algo nuevo en php y mysqli se me complica un poco a la hora de resolver estos problemas que de segura ha de ser una tontería.
Dejo por aquí los codes:

HTML FORM CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Inicia sesion my guy </title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="supremassy.jpg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_login.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="user_panel">
<form class="dov" action="load.php" method="POST">
<label for="usuario">
<span class="usuario"> Inserte su usuario </span>
</label>
<input class="username" type="text" name="usernames" id="supra_user" pattern=".{A-Za-z0-9}" placeholder="Usuario dado por Supremassy" required>
<label for="contrasena">
<span class="contrasena"> Inserte su contrasena </span>
</label>
<input class="password" type="password" name="contrasena" id="supra_pw" pattern=".{A-Za-z0-9}" placeholder="Contrasena dada por Supremassy" required>
<button type="submit"> Acceder </button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

CÓDIGO PHP

```
<?php
session_start();


$servername = "127.0.0.1";  // Host
$username = "root";  //User
$password = ''; // Password
$dbname = "prueba"; // dbname

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$connp = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

// Initialize the session


// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
  header("location: index.php");
  exit;
}
 

 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$usernames = $contrasena = "";
$username_err = $contrasena_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["usernames"]))){
        $username_err = "¿¿?? <p style{ color:red; } No eres bienvenido</p>";
    } else{
        $usernames = trim($_POST["usernames"]);
    }
    
    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["contrasena"]))){
        $contrasena_err = "Por favor ingrese su contraseña.";
    } else{
        $contrasena = trim($_POST["contrasena"]);
    }
    
    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($contrasena_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, contrasena FROM tata WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $usernames;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $usernames, $hashed_contrasena);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($contrasena, $hashed_contrasena)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();
                            
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["usernames"] = $usernames;                            
                            
                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: index.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $contrasena_err = "<span style{ color:red; font-weight: bold; } ¡Abandona o te abandonamos!</span>";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "<span style{ color:red; } Vas a desaparecer...";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Algo salió mal, por favor vuelve a intentarlo.";
            }
        }
        
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: Es raro que dé ese error. ¿Cual es la línea 36 en `load.php`? ¿Estás escribiendo datos en el input antes de enviar el formulario?

Comment: después de `session_start();` coloca esto: `var_dump($_POST);` y editas tu post y colocas lo que te haya salido por pantalla.